# GSpread how to duplicate sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

After googling and searching on Stackoveflow, I think I can't find a guide on how to duplicate existing sheet(existing Template sheet) and saving it into another sheet.

as per docs, there is [duplicate_sheet](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.add_worksheet) but I can't manage to do a working example, anyone that can guide me with this?

```
 import gspread
 from gspread.models import Cell, Spreadsheet

 scope = [
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
 ]

 json_key_absolute_path = "key.json"
 credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(json_key_absolute_path, scope)
 client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

 spreadsheet_client = Spreadsheet(client)
 spreadsheet_client.duplicate_sheet("18Qk5bzuA7JOBD8CTgwvKYRiMl_35it5AwcFG2Bi5npo", new_sheet_name="timcard2")
 worksheet = client.open("timcard2")
 worksheet.share("my_email@google.com", perm_type='user', role='writer')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- You want to copy the source Spreadsheet as new Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using gspread with python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Issue and solution:

It seems that `duplicate_sheet` method of gspread is used for copying a sheet in the source Spreadsheet to the same source Spreadsheet. [Ref](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/a52db7006f7906eca42fff058deb254526c4cb08/gspread/models.py#L364) In order to copy the source Spreadsheet as new Spreadsheet, pleas use the method of [`copy()`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.Client.copy) of Class Client.

#### Sample script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

spreadsheet_client = Spreadsheet(client)
spreadsheet_client.duplicate_sheet("18Qk5bzuA7JOBD8CTgwvKYRiMl_35it5AwcFG2Bi5npo", new_sheet_name="timcard2")
worksheet = client.open("timcard2")
worksheet.share("my_email@google.com", perm_type='user', role='writer')
```

To:

```
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
client.copy("18Qk5bzuA7JOBD8CTgwvKYRiMl_35it5AwcFG2Bi5npo", title="timcard2", copy_permissions=True)

worksheet = client.open("timcard2")
worksheet.share("my_email@google.com", perm_type='user', role='writer')
```

- When you run the script, the Spreadsheet which has the spreadsheet ID of `18Qk5bzuA7JOBD8CTgwvKYRiMl_35it5AwcFG2Bi5npo` is copied as the spreadsheet name of `timcard2`. And, the permission information of the source Spreadsheet is also copied.

#### Note:

- In this case, when `copy_permissions=True` is used, the permission information is also copied. So although I'm not sure about your actual situation, it might not be required to use `worksheet.share("my_email@google.com", perm_type='user', role='writer')`. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [duplicate_sheet](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.duplicate_sheet)
- [copy(file_id, title=None, copy_permissions=False)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.Client.copy)

### Added:

- You want to copy one of sheets in Google Spreadsheet.

I could understand like above. For this, the sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
client.copy("18Qk5bzuA7JOBD8CTgwvKYRiMl_35it5AwcFG2Bi5npo", title="timcard2", copy_permissions=True)

ss = client.open("timcard2")
ss.share("my_email@google.com", perm_type='user', role='writer')

delete_sheets = ["Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4"]  # Please set the sheet names you want to delete.
for s in delete_sheets:
    ss.del_worksheet(ss.worksheet(s))
```

- In this sample, the sheets of "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4" are deleted from the copied Spreadsheet.

#### Reference:

- [del_worksheet(worksheet)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.del_worksheet)

Comment: Thanks, I will check it as soon as I update my project

Comment: Hi, thanks its working but ... can it copy a specific sheet only? its copying the whole spreadsheet. Or I just open the spreadsheet and delete the unwanted sheets?

Comment: @Led Thank you for replying. I couldn't notice that you want to copy one of sheets in Spreadsheet. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. In your situation, I would like to recommend to copy the Spreadsheet and delete the unused sheets in the copied Spreadsheet. Because when `client.copy()` is used, the permission information can be also copied. I thought that this will be useful for your situation. For this, I added one more script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: i see, thanks for confirming. I already have the logic in deleting the sheet, but I was thinking if that was necessary or if there was a shortcut in the .copy. Thanks for the effort, Arigatou gozaimasu?

Comment: @Led Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Kotirakoso Arigatou.